# Reversed First Letter Caps?

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5

Hello i was just wondering is there anyway to reverse this code so that the first letter is lowercase and the rest of the word is caps?

```
Dim s As String = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
Dim s2 As String = StrConv(s, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
MessageBox.Show(s2)
```

I'm using .net frameworks 3.5

Here is the answer! Thanks Tim!

```
Dim s As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim s2 = String.Join(" ", s.Split() .Select(Function(w)UppercaseAllButFirst(w)).ToArray())
TextBox2.Text = s2
```

Comment: I don’t think there is an existing method for this – why should there be? It’s by and large a useless operation (when do you ever need it?). But it’s also trivial to write on your own.

Comment: create your own extension method

Comment: Instead of adding solved in the title, please upvote and mark Tim's answer if it helped.

Comment: thanks :) i didnt know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new function:

```
Public Shared Function UppercaseAllButFirst(s As String) As String
    ' check for empty string
    If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) Then
        Return String.Empty
    End If
    Return Char.ToLower(s(0)) & s.Substring(1).ToUpper()
End Function
```

Then you can use  it this way:

```
Dim s2 = String.Join(" ", s.Split().Select(Function(w) UppercaseAllButFirst(w)))
```

.NET 3.5, `String.Join` needs an array:

```
String.Join(" ", s.Split().Select(Function(w) UppercaseAllButFirst(w)).ToArray())
```

Comment: That doesn’t do what OP wants.

Comment: I tryed that and i couldn't seem to get it to work it can't find s in s.Split

Comment: @T3rr11: What means you "can't find s in s.Split"? Which .NET-framework version do you use?

Comment: Then you need to append `.ToArray()` to join all words. Edited my answer.

Comment: thanks :) I got it here's my code :)

            Dim s As String = TextBox1.Text
            Dim s2 = String.Join(" ", s.Split().Select(Function(w) UppercaseAllButFirst(w)).ToArray())
            TextBox2.Text = s2

Comment: Your code works for me, compiled as .net 3.5. This is the result in `TextBox2`: "tHE qUICK bROWN fOX jUMPS oVER tHE lAZY dOG".

Comment: Whoa, this code is waaaay too complicated. The function can be simplified by replacing the last statement with `Char.ToLower(s(0)) & s.Substring(1).ToUpper()`

Comment: @KonradRudolph: You're right. That happens if you modify existing code when the requirement changes a little bit ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
dim s1 as string="the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
dim s2 as string= _ 
     string.Join(" ",s1.Split(" ").Select (function(s) _
     s.Substring(0,1).ToLower()+s.Substring(1).ToUpper()).ToArray())
```

This will get you this output:

```
tHE qUICK bROWN fOX jUMPS oVER tHE lAZY dOG
```

Comment: It says "Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'."

Comment: Updated the answer. Have a look